# best way to create a savepoint in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have an application where users create cost models.
I would like to implement a feature where users can select a "trial" mode which allows them to make as many changes as they wish and observe the cost impact. 
If the trial is a success the user should be able to commit all changes, if unsuccessful the user should be able to rollback to the state before entering trial mode.

I know I could probably store all of this in the session and simply use commit or rollback, but is that the best practice here? Is there a better mechanism to set and restore the dbs state?

Comment: There are multiple ways to answer this. You could save their "trial" runs as actual records in the database, where the "real" records have a flag. Or, you could just let the user play with the data in the object model and not even save it to the database. If this is a web app, you can persist the object model in a cache (or the web session) using something like pickle. Exactly how you do this is really dependent on the requirements of your project, and even then what is the "best" way is pretty subjective.

Comment: One thing you might run into is that between multiple requests, the default scoped session will not suffice as it represents different sessions per request.

Answer (score 3):

There is example of savepoint usage. You can read more at [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint)

```
Session = sessionmaker()
session = Session()
session.add(u1)
session.add(u2)

session.begin_nested() # establish a savepoint
session.add(u3)
session.rollback()  # rolls back u3, keeps u1 and u2

session.commit() # commits u1 and u2
```